# add column to json php

Tags: php, json

I do an SQL query that I execute. The result is in the variable : `$result = $req->fetchAll();`

After this I do : `echo json_encode($result);` and I get :

```
[{"date":"2022","0":"2022","title":"KKKK","1":"KKKK","test":"haha","2":"haha"}]
```

But now I would like to add a field named `n` to every element of my json. So for example I will now get :

```
[{"date":"2022","0":"2022","title":"KKKK","1":"KKKK","test":"haha","2":"haha", "n" : "12", "3":"12"}]
```

i tried several things but it doesn't work. For example I tried the following before encoding :

```
foreach($result as &$row) {
    $row->n = "12";
}
```

Comment: It works for me. What happens when you try? - https://3v4l.org/bDH7v

Comment: You could add `n` to the SQL result `select ... '12' as n` you also should likely define your `fetch` method so you don't duplicate column returns

Comment: @aynber it throws the error : Warning: Attempt to assign property 'n' of non-object

Comment: @user3783243 oh that's clever I am going to try this method

Comment: I'm guessing that could mean that `$row` is an array instead of an object, so you can try `$row['n'] = 12;` instead